# Zero not returning in DB2 when select query yields no result

Tags: sql, ssis, db2

I am running the below select query in SSIS which is using DB2 connection.

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl.Test) AS NoOfDest
FROM tbl.Index
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

When this query yields no result, I am getting the below error in SSIS.

> single row result set is specified but no rows were returned.

So I am trying to return `0` in DB2 instead of 'blank/no result'. I have tried the below.

```
SELECT 
    (COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl.Test), 0)) AS NoOfDest
FROM tbl.Index
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;

SELECT 
    (NVL((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl.Test), 0)) AS NoOfDest
FROM tbl.Index
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

But everything returning no result.

How can I return 0 in DB2 ?

Comment: Just `SELECT COUNT(*) as NoOfDest FROM tbl.Test`?

Answer (score 3):

Presumably, it returns no result because `tbl.Index`.  Try this:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl.Test) AS NoOfDest
FROM sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

This begs the question why you are not simply doing:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)  AS NoOfDest
FROM tbl.Test;
```